# C++0x: how to get variadic template parameters without reference?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Given the following contrived (and yes, terrible) example:

```
template<typename... Args>
void something(Args... args)
{
    std::tuple<Args...> tuple; // not initializing for sake of example
    std::get<0>(tuple) = 5;
}
```

It works if you call it like so:

```
int x = 10;
something<int>(x);
```

However, it does not work if you call it like this:

```
int x = 10;
something<int&>(x);
```

Because of the assignment to 5.  Assuming that I cannot, for whatever reason, initialize the tuple when it is defined, how might I get this to work when specifying the type as a reference?

Specifically, I would like the tuple to be `std::tuple<int>` even when `Args...` is `int&`.

The actual use case for this involves deserializing a string into a tuple where `Args...` are the parameter types to a function that is then called by unpacking the tuple.  It all works great except when the function takes a parameter by reference.

I'm using gcc 4.5.2 but would accept an answer that isn't implemented yet in this compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't understand your question. This code works fine with GCC and I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Args>
void something(Args... args)
{
  std::tuple<Args...> tuple{args...};
  std::get<0>(tuple) = 5;
}

int main() {
  int x = 10;
  something<int&>(x);
}

[js@HOST2 cpp]$ g++ -std=c++0x main1.cpp
[js@HOST2 cpp]$
```

I don't know what you mean by "initialize the template".

---

Since you have now updated the question, I can update my answer

```
template<typename... Args>
void something(Args... args)
{
  std::tuple<typename std::decay<Args>::type...> tuple;
  std::get<0>(tuple) = 5;
}
```

`decay` removes `const` / `volatile`, removes references and transforms array and function types to element and function pointers respectively. That is what you seem to look for.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, "if I cannot initialize the tuple," IE can't include the {args...} you have in your example.

Comment: @Sydius then don't pass a reference type. You must initialize a reference. What would you expect `get<0>(tuple) = 5` assign to if you haven't initialized the reference?

Comment: I added clarification to my question.  I want the tuple to not be to a reference even when the template is for a reference.  The actual use case of this is much more complex; this is just a contrived example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Sydius then I think you should describe the more complex usecase (not its code, just its situation). All this is just dabbling around the real problem and the solution I would propose would only be a way to solve this reduced test case which possibly is not really a solution for your more complex usecase.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I want, but in gcc 4.5.2 I'm getting `expected a type, got ‘std::decay<Args>::type ...’`

Comment: I added the actual use case (in brief), but believe that, should I get my reduced case to work, I would be able to solve my issue.  I think `std::decay` sounds exactly what I want, if I could get it to compile.  Perhaps it's not fully supported in this context in gcc 4.5.2?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `std::tuple<std::remove_reference<Args>...>`?

Comment: I think I might be doing it wrong, but when I try that, I get: `error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘std::get [with long unsigned int __i = 0ul, _Elements = {std::remove_reference<int&>}, typename std::__add_ref<typename std::tuple_element<__i, std::tuple<_Elements ...> >::type>::type = std::remove_reference<int&>&](((std::tuple<std::remove_reference<int&> >&)(& tuple))) = 5’`

Comment: When you use a metafunction you have to access its return type unless you actually want to use the metafunction as a type itself.  I forgot that in my post.  I think the syntax should be `std::remove_reference<Args>::type ...`